# CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.LogOnException: Database logon failed

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

This happens on **ReportDocument.Export()** for a PDF generation.
But only sporadically/randomly.

In the overall picture it's not that bad, 1 or 2 errors per day (+10k request), but still this bugs me.

2 different kinds of errors:

- CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.LogOnException: *Database logon failed*.
- CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.LogOnException: *Error in File* < Reportname >.rpt
  *Unable to connect: incorrect log on parameters*

I see that these errors are quite common in the community, i've found lots of sites with solutions to these error, i've  tried a lot of them, but none have worked so far (one exception i'll mention below).

## Facts

- Version used is 13.0.21.2533 (SAP Crystal Reports runtime engine for .NET Framework (32 and 64 bits))
- The reports generated work in all environments (even prod)
- Some reports randomly/sporadically fail. Although the same (request) report can be generated almost immediately working fine.
- No report viewer.
- The fact that they work in prod, for me, discards many of the proposed solutions. Regardless i tried/checked them.
- No connection to DB, i'm passing a DataSet as the DataSource of the report (multiple tables inside)
- I use an "Using" pattern/syntax. I also tried explicitly disposing on Finally (isntead of using)

```
            finally
            {
                report.Database.Dispose();
                report.Close();
                report.Dispose();
            }
```

## Testing/Replicating

To be able to replicate the issue, i use *SOAP UI* to Load test the request (1 minute, 2 threads, as many (exactly the same) requests as possible) and from time to time, one fails.

## Error 1. Database Logon failed

This one is partially solved, i changed from setting the datasource this way:

```
                report.SetDataSource(rawData);
```

to setting it for each table in the datasource, more or less like this:

```
                foreach (DataTable dataTable in rawData.Tables)
                {
                    foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table table in report.Database.Tables)
                    {
                        if (table.Name == dataTable.TableName)
                        {
                            table.SetDataSource(dataTable);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

This fix removes almost entirely this error, almost.
I need more aggressive Load testing to get it to fail once sporadically, while previously it failed ,once or twice, each and every time i load tested it.

## Error 2. Error in File < Reportname >.rpt.     Unable to connect: incorrect log on parameters

With the fix above, there are also few instances of this error (1 or 2 exceptions), also need more aggressive load testing to happen, but occurs more than the above one. before it failed 3 to 7 times per load test.

## Errors

```
An exception is thrown: 
     >>>>> Exception details=CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.LogOnException: Database logon failed. 
                        ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Database logon failed.
                        
       at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers.ReportSourceClass.Export(ExportOptions pExportOptions, RequestContext pRequestContext)
       at CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.EromReportSourceBase.ExportToStream(ExportRequestContext reqContext)
       
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
       at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ConvertDotNetToErom.ThrowDotNetException(Exception e)
       at CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.EromReportSourceBase.ExportToStream(ExportRequestContext reqContext)
       at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.FormatEngine.ExportToStream(ExportRequestContext reqContext)
       at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.FormatEngine.Export(ExportRequestContext reqContext)
       at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.FormatEngine.Export()
       at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Export()
       at < mynamespace >.RptUtil.GeneratePDF(DataSet rawData, ...
```

the other one

```
    An exception is thrown: 
     >>>>> Exception details=CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.LogOnException: Error in File < 
report name >_{1E5E29F7-E5A2-43EA-90E5-D62ECAA19A01}.rpt:
    Unable to connect: incorrect log on parameters. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Error in File < 
report name >_{1E5E29F7-E5A2-43EA-90E5-D62ECAA19A01}.rpt:
    Unable to connect: incorrect log on parameters.

       at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers.ReportSourceClass.Export(ExportOptions pExportOptions, RequestContext pRequestContext)
       at CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.EromReportSourceBase.ExportToStream(ExportRequestContext reqContext)

       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
       at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ConvertDotNetToErom.ThrowDotNetException(Exception e)
       at CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.EromReportSourceBase.ExportToStream(ExportRequestContext reqContext)
       at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.FormatEngine.ExportToStream(ExportRequestContext reqContext)
       at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.FormatEngine.Export(ExportRequestContext reqContext)
       at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.FormatEngine.Export()
       at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Export()
       at < mynamespace >.RptUtil.GeneratePDF(DataSet rawData, ...
```

Comment: I have this problem once because an option was turned on. I'm trying to remember the name. I think if you right click the data source in the designer, a context menu will pop up with two options. One is to refresh. The other is some think like "verify on each something". It was accidentally checked. When i turned it off, it did not happen anymore. It is a long shot, since it is not the default behavior, but maybe it is worth a try.

Comment: this is weird, i answered just after you commented but i don't see my comments to your comments. Let me comment again, "Verify on first refresh", and some others settings also checked... nevertheless the report usually works, just fails sporadically...